# My prestashop site keep loading with no data?

Tags: php, apache, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I move my site to another server , the only difference is php version of the last server is 5.6 and in the new server is 7.1, my prestashop version is 1.6.1.17,
I don't get any result in log , even mode debug is enabled but site always load without result,the site work only when I disabled modules or I change theme to default_bootstrap and this As you know disabled all theme modules, and this 46 modules.
I think that the probleme is in one or many of this modules.
I don't know how I can fix this error

Comment: Please format the question - Read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: please , can you edit my question because I can't find where is it the probleme in it

Comment: You get blank page? Have you checked server error log?

Comment: yes and I don't get any error

Comment: delete all files and folders (except index.php) within the /cache folder and try again